# When I read that mp3 stream is 192 Kbps, is that bit or bytes?

Tags: byte, media, bit

I want to make a radio android app with my favorite internet stations. For each station I have several MP3 streams to choose from:

- 64 Kbps
- 128 Kbps
- 192 Kbps

Is the "b" on "Kbps" bit or byte? If it is bit, streaming 192 Kbps MP3 stream would result in 56Mb/hour? Fine on Wi-Fi, but not very dataplan friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kbps stands for Kilobits per second - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Kilobit_per_second